# Error in inserting data in bean

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am trying to insert data in a table Order having following fields:
id PK,
cid FK,
pid FK,

I am trying to insert data in this order bean.

**Here is my JSP code:**

```
<form:form>
    <form:hidden path="id"/>
    <table cellpadding="2px">
    <tr><td><label>Customer ID</label></td><td><form:input path="cid"/><form:errors   path="cid" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Package ID</label></td><td><form:input path="pid"/><form:errors     path="pid" /></td></tr>      
    <tr align="center"><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save Changes"     /></td></tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

**and here is Controller Code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/editorder", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String EditPerson(Model model){
            model.addAttribute("command", new Order());     
            return "/WEB-INF/pages/orders/editorder.jsp";
        }
```

**I am getting Error: (I mentioned only root cause here)**

root cause
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cid' of bean class [com.order.domain.Order]: Bean property 'cid' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Any solution please?

```
Here is Order bean:
package com.order.domain;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order extends BaseEntity{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="cid")
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="pid")
    private Packagee package1;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="order")
    private List<Feedback> feedbacks;

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Packagee getPackage1() {
        return package1;
    }

    public void setPackage1(Packagee package1) {
        this.package1 = package1;
    }

    public List<Feedback> getFeedbacks() {
        return feedbacks;
    }

    public void setFeedbacks(List<Feedback> feedbacks) {
        this.feedbacks = feedbacks;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you carefully read the error message? What don't you understand in it? Given that it's talking about getters and setters of the com.order.domain.Order class, don't you think the code of this class might be relevant?

Comment: I have check it carefully but I found no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

> Invalid property 'cid' of bean class [com.order.domain.Order]: Bean property 'cid' is not readable or has an invalid getter method

So, Spring is looking for a getter for the property `cid` in the class `com.order.domain.Order`:

```
public Long getCid() {
    ...
}
```

And there is no such getter in your class.

Comment: I have added a getter in my bean as follows: 
 public int getCid(){
  return customer.getId();
 }
but it gives error again which says: HTTP Status 500 - org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'cid' of bean class [com.order.domain.Order]: Getter for property 'cid' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Then make sure your getter doesn't throw an exception.